# Multi step reasoner in c++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, search, functional-programming, artificial-intelligence

I am looking for a simple implementation of a planner/search algorithm implemented as compile time c++ templates. The application for such a thing is partly academic, partly driven by practical needs for code verification.

Here is the essence of what I am looking for: Imagine a search algorithm to plan actions from a 'Start' state to a 'End' state.

```
template<A, B> struct Step{
   //all steps have:
   static void doAction();
}


struct Start{};
struct State1{};
struct State2{};
struct End{};


//Transition between neighbor-states is known:

template<> struct<Start, State1>{
     static void doAction(){
         std::cout << "Start -> State1" << std::endl;
     }
};

template<> struct<State1, State2>{
     static void doAction(){
         std::cout << "State1 -> State2" << std::endl;
     }
};

template<> struct<State2, End>{
     static void doAction(){
         std::cout << "State2 -> End" << std::endl;
     }
};
```

Now I would like to use the magic of templates to find a sequence of steps (using SFINAE or other tricks). How can the following be achieved?

```
 //TODO: Implement a reasoner:
 template<typename A, typename B, typename C> struct Step<A,C>{
    typedef Step<A,B> S1;
    typedef Step<B,C> S2;

    static void doAction(){
         S1::doAction();
         S2::doAction();
    }
 };


// Code using it:
Step<Start, State1>::doAction(); //Expect: "Start -> State1" 

Step<Start, State2>::doAction(); // Expect: "Start -> State1" 
                                 //         "State1 -> State2"

Step<Start, End>::doAction();    // Expect: "Start -> State1"
                                 //         "State1 -> State2"
                                 //         "State2 -> End"
```

Comment: Despite all your efforts the question looks still vague. But intriguing. Let's try to refine it. How would a 'result' look like?

Comment: Finding a single unique solution probably is doable (brute-force). A "shortest" solution sounds like a nightmare.

Comment: A single unique solution fits the bill. It does not need to be optimized. The idea is to get certainty about some properties at compile time.

Comment: There's probably a better way to do this, but http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f41bb24699f9901

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best solved backwards. Define `Path<End>::cost == 0` and reasoning backwards `Path<State2,End>::cost==Path<End>::cost + 1` because there's a `Step<State2,End>`.

Your `PathFinder` algorithm would need a list of all states to consider, though: it can't discover them given your definition of states and `Step<>`

Comment: If there is a larger set of states and a few transitions between them known, the compiler should be able to answer if it is possible to get from one state to a given other state. Can you elaborate on how to achieve that using your approach? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user1362700: The idea is that two paths are connected if and only if there's a `Path<begin, ... , End>` class. That's why you need that list of states. Given `Path<..., S1>`, you define `Path<...,S1,S2>` if `Step<S1,S2>` exists. As an optimization, you can remove states from the open list once you've reached them. This is fairly straightforward functional programming.